# Moved Wordpress site and on login redirects to home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I meticulously backed up a working WordPress site, files DB tables, the works. I moved it to a new server, got everything working, the site renders, the DB is recognized, etc.

The issue is anytime I try to log-in, after login the site always redirects to the homepage `(mysite.com/index.php)`

I have scoured every PHP page for text like 'site_url' and 'wp-redirect' 'redirect' looking for the offending code that will not direct me to the admin dashboard.

To be honest, I am not even sure what page the site is supposed to redirect to.

I can always reinstall, but then I'd get stuck with the daunting task of having to manually rebuild all the headers, with the images, embedded flash and the rest of it.

Since the site was working at the previous location, and not a single byte was lost on the move, with all the tables updated to show the correct server name, I am stuck on this issue.

I have looked at all the StackOverflow links related to this issue and none of them addressed my issue specifically.

Comment: Did you correct site url and home url in the database? and check the wp-config.php``

Comment: Yes, I did both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-install WP altogether. Once I did that, I was able to login and see the WP dashboard.

To reinstall, I relocated all the files in the main directory and the wp-admin, wp-content, and wp-includes folder. All the other folders I left alone, because they are not affected by the WP install.

After the install, you will have to open the wp-config.php file to input the new db name, db user, db password and db host. What you will see is the WP install added a fresh set of tables in the db you named in the config file. The only folder you will then have to copy and paste is the theme folder from the old site into the themes folder in your new install.

Now that you can login (yoursite.com/wp-admin), to populate your dashboard, import all the records from the old db table into the new one (the one with the pages and posts you want). If you do that right, all the pages (and blog posts) should populate in the dashboard window.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress never does such redirection. Some security plugin can do. To fix the issue. deactivate all the plugins, you can do this by executing following query

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '' WHERE `option_name` = 'active_plugins';
```

Once done login and activate the plugins one by one and check which one causing the issue.

Comment: Still redirecting to the home page.

Comment: check with your htaccess file. rename this file and try